# Joomla Kunena Fourm Remote path issue

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have been trying to fix this without success.

Lately, I am trying to build up a forum using Kunena forum with joomla. I build it all in my local server. When I uploaded the files to the remote server, I got the problem when I access the backend Kunena control panel as follow:

500 - An error has occurred.
load error: failed to find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/abacdeal1/media/kunena/less/bootstrap/kunena.less

I couldn't find where to change that directory.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue as I was having the same problem myself.

Go to `root/cache/kunena`

In there is a cache file for `less` which all you need to do is simply delete.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-download the Kunena package from http://www.kunena.org/download, extract files on your PC, open packages folder -> kunena_media_v3.0.0.zip (extract-it) -> open less folder -> open bootstrap and here is "kunena.less". Now, upload this file to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/abacdeal1/media/kunena/less/bootstrap/ on your server and refresh your site.

Now it must works!

I hope it will works.

PS: when you copy (upload files) from your PC to your own server, some files may not copy correct because of files permissions.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue. The file is there, however it's still trying to get the file from his MAMP server instead of online one.

Comment: what is the version of Joomla that you are using?

Comment: I was using the latest Kunena version but I've solved the problem now

Answer (score 0):

Using Joomla 3.6 and Kunena 5.0.

I built a test site and them moved it over to my production domain name. That caused Load Error Failed to Find Kunena Crypsis.less whenever I clicked on the menu item for Kunena Forum.

My solution was to clear cache in Joomla.